# Filter from array of json objects using underscore js

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

[image]
So basically 'collections' is an array of json objects where each object contains a property, 'categories' which contains id like 82, 84 etc. So i want to filter the 'collections' objects, for whom categories will be 82(input parameter: 'category_id') and store them into a variable using Underscore js. (P.S- use _.filter)

Comment: So, the most asked question on these questions is, what have you tried till now, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, _.filter method does the same as Array.filter method. not sure you need to use underscore here.

```
function filterCollections(collectionsArray, categoryId) {
    return collectionsArray.filter((collection) => {
        return collection.categories.indexOf(categoryId) > -1;
    })
}
```

Using underscore it should be something like this:

```
function filterCollections(collectionsArray, categoryId) {
    return _.filter(collectionsArray, (collection) => {
        return collection.categories.indexOf(categoryId) > -1;
    })
}
```

If your input is json string, you need to parse it to Array with JSON.parse()

```
collectionsArray = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: I got it where I did mistake. Now its filtering. Thank you.